# How can a second mock user be authenticated in a Mocha Chai test in a FeathersJS app?

Tags: unit-testing, mocha.js, chai, feathersjs

I have followed the chapter about [Testing in the FeathersJS Docs](https://docs.feathersjs.com/testing/readme.html) and everything went well.

Now I would like to create a second mock user to test that users cannot update a document they haven't created.

Here is the code I use to create mock users and get an authentication token:

```
  var createUserSetToken = (user, cb) => {
    User.create({
      'email': user.email,
      'password': user.password
    }, () => {
      chai.request(app)
        .post('/auth/local')
        .set('Accept', 'application/json')
        .send({
          'email': user.email,
          'password': user.password
        })
        .end((err, res) => {
          //set token for auth in other requests
          user.token = res.body.token;
          cb();
        });
    });
  }
```

It works well if I use it multiple times in my test file if provide the same user each time (which is rather useless) and fails as soon as I try to use it with a different user.

I thought the reason might be that some kind of logout or 'revoke token' operation has to be performed first but I couldn't find anything in the docs or by browsing the web. So how should I proceed to be able to use multiple mock users in the Mocha tests?